# Eclipse - Choosing servers in "Run on server" vs setting "Target Runtime"

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

When we create a dynamic web project in Eclipse, we get an option to set a Target Runtime. This basically sets the classpath to make sure our project finds all the necessary server classes required for the project to run. Then when we run the project by clicking on "Run as"->"Run on Server", we get a list of servers once again to choose from. I know that we can always select the "Always use this server when running the project". But my question is what is the rationale behind presenting the user with a list of servers to choose from to run their project on once again when you have already selected the Target Runtime. Is it like a "Test your project on a different server from your Target Runtime" feature???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify the server runtime environments for your project, server container JARs will be contributed to your project's class path. Also IDE will not allow you to add any project facets not supported by the target runtime server. This means that target runtime will determine possible project facets.
Once project is created, server container class path will contribute to class path of the project, so any JARs required by project and available in server container will be available to your project. For example, if you project requires Java Servlet API and you add Apache Tomcat as Target Runtime, Tomcat Catalina - Java Servlet API will be available on project class path and all JARs provided by this runtime environment will be used for compilation. This means that you do not need to add manually Servlet API JARs to your project class path, target runtime will provide them.
After compilation, once all necessary JARs are included you can run your project on other server, it does not necessary have to be run only on your target runtime.
For example while developing Java Web Application targeted for Apache Tomcat, after compilation you can deploy it on another servlet container or application server.

Also application or web server might use different JDK version for their JRE, than your current project version. By specifying target runtime server you ensure that correct libraries are used on the project.

Answer to your last question : Target Runtime will contribute Servlet API so you can compile your project. Otherwise you will have to add JAR's manually to use Servlet API, for example HttpServlet or HttpServletRequest or HttpServletResponse objects. Without allocating JARs on a class path, one way or the other you won't be able to compile, because dependencies are not resolved. Regarding your question, which implementation will be used at runtime - it depends on project setup. For example if you are using maven as your build tool, in maven you can declare scope of dependency : compile scope which is default, means that dependencies should be available in class paths of your project during compilation. But if you indicate provided scope - it means that JDK or server container will provide dependency at runtime. So in case of Servlet API for example if you indicate scope of dependency as provided you ll get Servlet API provided by servlet container at runtime, i.e. same container you choose "Run on server"

Comment: That's interesting.....So correct me if i am wrong. So you are saying I can add Target Runtime just to be able to compile my project i.e. I can use a Java Servlet Implementation from Tomcat to compile my project. But when it comes time to run the project i can get my project to run for example the JBoss Implementation of a Java Servlet (i.e. by Choosing to Run on a different Server). So my compilation uses one implementation of Servlet API. My runtime uses a different implementation.

Comment: Or are you saying I can take the Servlet Implementation classes from Tomcat and have my project use them during runtime on a JBoss Server for example

Comment: I have updated my post with the answer to your last question. It does not fit into commen.

Comment: Thank you so much. That gives me the clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Look inside your projects libraries folder. You'll see a folder that comes from your runtime server like "Apache Tomcat v7.0". This gives your project dependencies like "javax.servlet". If you right click your project > properties > targeted runtimes you can remove the server runtime and see what happens. The Apache Tomcat library will disappear and your project all of a sudden is missing dependencies. Add it back and the errors go away.